# Unsure why BS4 and selenium not return correctly

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

#selenium Path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok')

#PAGE SCROLLING
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

#BS4 taking Selenium Driver Source
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-card__info disable-animations for--product')

#Iterate Through HTML and filter out content as needed and store inside shoes.csv
with open('shoes.csv','w', encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
  thewriter= writer(f)
  header=['Name','Price']
  thewriter.writerow(header)
  for list in lists:
    try:
            name = list.find('div', class_='product-card__title').text
            price = list.find('div',class_='product-price css-11s12ax is--current-price').text
    except:
            print("\nList finished!")
            break
    info = [name,price]
    thewriter.writerow(info)
    print(info)
#testing for other tag 
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
lists2 = soup2.find_all('div', class_='product-card__info disable-animations for--product')
#testing
with open('shoes2.csv','w', encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
  thewriter= writer(f)
  header=['Name','Price']
  thewriter.writerow(header)
  for list in lists2:
    try:
            names = list.find('div', class_='product-card__title').text
            prices = list.find('div',class_='product-price is--current-price css-s56yt7').text
    except:
            print("\nList finished!")
            break
    info2 = [names,prices]
    thewriter.writerow(info2)
    print(info2)
```

The intent is to build a web scraper for search through the Nike Men Shoes Store and output a `CSV` file with the name and price of item

So on the the website it show 500+ items and I'm only able to gather 100 items....

I double check all the tags and notice when i print out the `HTML` its skipping item randomly! If anyone could tell me why I would greatly appreciated

**UPDATE SOLVE using purely selenium!**

will be using the webdriver opinion to use headless browser to further lessen resource load! any tip for make it more efficient would be appreciated

```
import requests
from csv import writer
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import itertools


#selenium Path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok')

#PAGE SCROLLING
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = .5
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
Wname=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card__title")
Wprice=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card__price")
Wcolor=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card__product-count")

#Make 3 seperate list to translate over to text
name=[]
price=[]
color=[]
for i in Wname :
  name.append(i.text)
for i in Wprice:
  price.append(i.text)
for i in Wcolor:
  color.append(i.text)

#making CSV 
new_list=[]
with open('Menshoes.csv','w', encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
  thewriter= writer(f)
  header=['Name','Price','#Color']
  thewriter.writerow(header)
  for n,p,q in itertools.zip_longest(name,price,color):
    if n:
        new_list.append(n)
    if p:
        new_list.append(p)
    if q:
        new_list.append(q)
    info = [n,p,q]
    thewriter.writerow(info)
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a closer look on your selection with `BeautifulSoup` it only provides specific cards as `ResultSet` which correspond to your class specification :

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='product-card__info disable-animations for--product')
```

You should use a more general selection to get more cards shown in your `ResultSet`:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='product-card__body')
```

**Note:** *Also avoid using [reserved keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) like `list`*

---

While scrolling give a bit more time or wait until all elements are loaded -  I stored the results in a list of dicts, so it is a bit more structured and I could perform some other things (check `len()` or `set()`) on it before writing it to csv.

```
...
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

#BS4 taking Selenium Driver Source
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
data = []

for e in soup.find_all('div', class_='product-card__body'):
    data.append({
        'name': e.select_one('.product-card__titles').text,
        'price':e.select_one('.is--current-price').text
    })
    
with open('shoes.csv','w', encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = data[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
...
```

Comment: so i solve it by completely not using beautiful soup and just purely using selenium ! 

```

Comment: @Zero404NF - If so, you could post your code as answer.